# Checking current user created the document in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am not able to check the UID of the document present in the Firebase with the id of the current userid in android studio. I did this and the log statement is showing 0. It should show 5.

**Analyze.kt**

```
class Analyze : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val db = Firebase.firestore
    private val myCollectionRef = db.collection("posts")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_analyze)
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        readData(object: MyCallback {
            override fun onCallback(value: HashMap<String,Int>) {
                Log.d("TAG", value.size.toString())
            }
        })
    }
    private fun readData(myCallback : MyCallback) {
        myCollectionRef.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val hashMap : HashMap<String, Int> = HashMap()
                val userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid.toString()

                for (document in task.result) {
                    val id = document.getString("uid").toString()
                    if (userId!=id) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    val amount = document.getString("amount")?.let { Integer.parseInt(it) }
                    val locate = document.getString("locate").toString()
                    if (hashMap.containsKey(locate)) {
                        val count = hashMap[locate] ?: 0
                        hashMap[locate] = count + amount!!
                    } else {
                        hashMap[locate] = amount!!
                    }
                }
                myCallback.onCallback(hashMap)
            }
        }
    }
    interface MyCallback {
        fun onCallback(value: HashMap<String,Int>)
    }
}
```

**Post.kt**

```
data class Post (
    val amount: String = "",
    val createdBy: User = User(),
    val createdAt: Long = 0L,
    val locate: String = "")
```

**User.kt**

```
data class User(val uid: String = "",
                val displayName: String? = "",
                val imageUrl: String = "")
```

[image]

I wanted to get all the documents that are created by the current user. I tried to get the UID that is inside createdBy from the document and tried to match it with the current user signed in. If the user does not match then just continue and move to the next document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `uid` field is nested in a map called `createdBy`. But when you do `document.getString("uid").toString()`, it looks for a top-level `uid` field.

The best way to fix this problem is to use a query to get only the documents where `createdBy.uid` has the value you are looking for:

```
myCollectionRef
  .whereEqualTo("createdBy.uid", userId)
  .get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    ...
```

Since this query now only retrieves the document you want, you no longer need the `if (userId!=id) {` in your callback.

Comment: I tried this solution and it is throwing this error- Cannot access 'where': it is package-private in 'CollectionReference'

Comment: Oops, I had a syntax error there. Corrected, based on https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#kotlin+ktx_1